# WCF VS 2015 multiple endpoints

Tags: c#, wcf

I wrote Contract, Host and Client and I must to create extra endpoints for the same service

CONTRACT iService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceContractLZ
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IKalkulatorLZ
    {
        [OperationContract]
        LiczbaZ DodajLZ(LiczbaZ n1, LiczbaZ n2);

        [OperationContract]
        void Funkcja1(String s1);
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void Funkcja2(String s2);
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class LiczbaZ
    {
        string opis = "Liczba zespolona";
        [DataMember]
        public double czescR;
        [DataMember]
        public double czescU;
        [DataMember]
        public string Opis
        {
            get { return opis; }
            set { opis = value; }
        }
        public LiczbaZ(double czesc_rz, double czesc_ur)
        {
            this.czescR = czesc_rz;
            this.czescU = czesc_ur;
        }
    }
}
```

CONTRACT Service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace WcfServiceContractLZ
{
    public class KalkulatorLZ : IKalkulatorLZ
    {
        public LiczbaZ DodajLZ(LiczbaZ n1, LiczbaZ n2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wywolanie: DodajLZ");
            return new LiczbaZ(n1.czescR + n2.czescR,
            n1.czescU + n2.czescU);
        }
        public void Funkcja1(String s1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: funkcja1 - start", s1);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: funkcja1 - stop", s1);
            return;
        }
        public void Funkcja2(String s2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: funkcja2 - start", s2);
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: funkcja2 - stop", s2);
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

HOST Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WcfServiceContractLZ;

namespace WcfServiceHostLZ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress2 = new Uri("http://loclahost:3000");
            String baseAddress3 = "net.tcp://localhost:4000/SerwisTCP";

            ServiceHost mojHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(KalkulatorLZ));
            try
            {
                ServiceEndpoint endpoint1 = mojHost.Description.Endpoints.Find(new Uri("http://localhost:2000/WcfService1/KalkulatorLZ"));
                Console.WriteLine("\nService endpoint {0} contains the following:",
                endpoint1.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Binding: {0}", endpoint1.Binding.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Contract: {0}", endpoint1.Contract.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUri: {0}", endpoint1.ListenUri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUriMode: {0}",endpoint1.ListenUriMode.ToString());

                ServiceEndpoint endpoint2 = mojHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IKalkulatorLZ), new WSHttpBinding(),"KalkulatorLZ2");
                Console.WriteLine("\nService endpoint {0} contains the following:",
                endpoint2.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Binding: {0}", endpoint2.Binding.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Contract: {0}", endpoint2.Contract.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUri: {0}", endpoint2.ListenUri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUriMode: {0}", endpoint2.ListenUriMode.ToString());

                ServiceEndpoint endpoint3 = mojHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IKalkulatorLZ), new WSHttpBinding(),baseAddress2);
                Console.WriteLine("\nService endpoint {0} contains the following:",
                endpoint3.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Binding: {0}", endpoint3.Binding.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Contract: {0}", endpoint3.Contract.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUri: {0}", endpoint3.ListenUri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUriMode: {0}", endpoint3.ListenUriMode.ToString());

                ServiceEndpoint endpoint4 = mojHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IKalkulatorLZ), new NetTcpBinding(),baseAddress3);
                Console.WriteLine("\nService endpoint {0} contains the following:",
                endpoint4.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("Binding: {0}", endpoint4.Binding.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Contract: {0}", endpoint4.Contract.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUri: {0}", endpoint4.ListenUri.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("ListenUriMode: {0}", endpoint4.ListenUriMode.ToString());


                mojHost.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("*** Serwis 1 jest uruchomiony ***");

                ContractDescription cd = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IKalkulatorLZ));
                Console.WriteLine("Displaying information for contract: {0}",
                cd.Name.ToString());
                string configName = cd.ConfigurationName;
                Console.WriteLine("\tConfiguration name: {0}", configName);
                Type contractType = cd.ContractType;
                Console.WriteLine("\tContract type: {0}", contractType.ToString());
                bool hasProtectionLevel = cd.HasProtectionLevel;
                if (hasProtectionLevel)
                {
                    ProtectionLevel protectionLevel = cd.ProtectionLevel;
                    Console.WriteLine("\tProtection Level: {0}",
                    protectionLevel.ToString());
                }
                string name = cd.Name;
                Console.WriteLine("\tName: {0}", name);
                string namespc = cd.Namespace;
                Console.WriteLine("\tNamespace: {0}", namespc);
                OperationDescriptionCollection odc = cd.Operations;
                Console.WriteLine("\tDisplay Operations:");
                foreach (OperationDescription od in odc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + od.Name);
                }
                SessionMode sm = cd.SessionMode;
                Console.WriteLine("\tSessionMode: {0}", sm.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Nacisnij <ENTER> aby zakonczyc.");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.ReadLine();
                mojHost.Close();
            }
            catch (CommunicationException ce)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wystapil wyjatek: {0}", ce.Message);
                mojHost.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HOST app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
<system.serviceModel>
 <services>
 <service name="WcfServiceContractLZ.KalkulatorLZ"
 behaviorConfiguration="Wydajnosc">
 <endpoint address="/KalkulatorLZ" binding="wsHttpBinding"
 contract="WcfServiceContractLZ.IKalkulatorLZ">
 <identity>
 <dns value="localhost" />
 </identity>
 </endpoint>
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
 contract="IMetadataExchange" />
 <host>
 <baseAddresses>
 <add baseAddress="http://localhost:2000/WcfService1" />
 </baseAddresses>
 </host>
 </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
 <serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="Wydajnosc">
 <serviceThrottling
 maxConcurrentCalls="5"
 maxConcurrentSessions="5"
 maxConcurrentInstances="5"
 />
 <serviceMetadata
 httpGetEnabled="true"
 httpGetUrl=""
 />
 </behavior>
 </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

CLIENT Program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WcfServiceClientLZ.ServiceReference1;
using WcfServiceContractLZ;

namespace WcfServiceClientLZ
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            KalkulatorLZClient client = new KalkulatorLZClient();
            LiczbaZ lru1 = new LiczbaZ(3, 4);
            LiczbaZ lru2 = new LiczbaZ(5, 6);
            Console.WriteLine("Klient1:");
            Console.WriteLine("...Dodaj LZ (3,4) i (5,6)");
            LiczbaZ result2 = client.DodajLZ(lru1, lru2);
            Console.WriteLine("...(3,4) + (5,6) = ({0},{1})",
            result2.czescR, result2.czescU);
            Console.WriteLine("...wywolanie funkcji 1");
            client.Funkcja1("Klient 1");
            Console.WriteLine("...kontynuacja po funkcji 1");
            Console.WriteLine("...wywolanie funkcji 2");
            client.Funkcja2("Klient 1");
            Console.WriteLine("...kontynuacja po funkcji 2");

            KalkulatorLZClient client2 = new KalkulatorLZClient("WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ2");
            Console.WriteLine("...wywolanie funkcji 1");
            client2.Funkcja1("Klient 2");

            KalkulatorLZClient client3 = new KalkulatorLZClient("WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ1");
            Console.WriteLine("...wywolanie funkcji 1");
            client3.Funkcja1("Klient 3");

            KalkulatorLZClient client4 = new KalkulatorLZClient("NetTcpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ");
            Console.WriteLine("...wywolanie funkcji 1");
            client4.Funkcja1("Klient 4");
            client.Close();
            client2.Close();
            client3.Close();
            client4.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ" />
            </netTcpBinding>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ" />
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ1" />
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ2" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2000/WcfService1/KalkulatorLZ"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IKalkulatorLZ" name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2000/WcfService1/KalkulatorLZ2"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IKalkulatorLZ" name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ1">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="KAROLA\Karolina" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://loclahost:3000/" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ2" contract="ServiceReference1.IKalkulatorLZ"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ2">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="KAROLA\Karolina" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:4000/SerwisTCP" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ" contract="ServiceReference1.IKalkulatorLZ"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IKalkulatorLZ">
                <identity>
                    <userPrincipalName value="KAROLA\Karolina" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the result in command promt, Host run okey but client is giving me this: More than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Soap Client Issue - more than one endpoint configuration for th at contract was found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17545175/c-sharp-soap-client-issue-more-than-one-endpoint-configuration-for-th-at-contr)

Comment: there is no duplicate, they are different

Comment: I agree, this is a duplicate of the linked question.  I expect the answer to that question will answer this.

Comment: but i don't see solution of my problem there, i am on very low level in C#